# Firefox extension to allow efficient searches?

Tags: firefox, search-engine, search

Firefox just got updated to version 43.  With that update, perhaps the most useful extension, [Quick Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quicksearch/), no longer works.

The developer has stated that he does not want to get it working, but is open to give the extension to another person.  Hopefully someone will continue the project.

But in the meantime, I am looking for something to replace it.

Quick Search Bar efficiently solved two main tasks:

1. It showed icons for all the user's search engines in a configurable bar.  The user could simply click on one of the visible icons and immediately enter text in the same bar to perform a search.  It was incredibly efficient.
2. It allowed the user to drag-and-drop *any* text onto one of those icons.  This would immediately search for that text using the target search engine.  It was elegant and efficient.

Can anyone recommend a Firefox extension to (at least temporarily) replace Quick Search Bar?  I would prefer one extension, but if it takes multiple extensions, so be it.

Comment: Cool, didn't know the one I use has that drag-n-drop! Can you check whether [Second Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/second-search/) still works? I'm still on FF42, so I can't tell about FF43 :)

Comment: @Izzy Before posting this, I took a look at Second Search, but it didn't look like it would add much to drag-and-drop.  I'll take another look.  I have tried quite a few different search extensions, and none of them work with Firefox 43.  One of them even locked it up!

Comment: Ouch. I've just tried shortly to mark some text, then drag it to the search box. That opened a "pop-up" to let me drop the text on the engine of choice. When typing in the box, it works similar: you simply select the target-engine via cursor keys, or hit enter for your default engine.

Comment: I'll assume you are referring to Second Search.  If so, I will definitely give it a try!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course – sorry for not being clear! I'm using SecondSearch for years now. So if it doesn't have the same fate concerning FF43, I'd make that an answer.

Comment: I gave *Second Search* a try.  Although not as efficient as *Quick Search Bar*, it allows similar functionality.  Unfortunately, in Firefox 43, it prevents autosuggest from working properly in the urlbar (Location Bar): no suggestions appear as you type.  That's a dealbreaker. :-(

Comment: Ouch. But it works fine in its own place (search-bar)? Because if not, I need to prevent my Firefox from updating itself, as that would be a dealbreaker for me. Also please let me know if I should make it an answer nevertheless (you didn't list urlbar with your requirements, after all), so we could cleanup the comments. That urlbar thingy might not be a dealbreaker for someone else – and finally, noone forces you to accept my answer then (no, I won't abuse my mod-powers for that ;)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  It currently breaks the native Firefox functionality for the urlbar in Firefox 43.  If you use that functionality (I would guess most people do), you will either need to stick with Firefox 42 or lose Second Search.  It's also possible it is an extension conflict... I have not tried it on a clean profile yet.  Note that Firefox 43 includes important security patches.

Comment: I use the URL bar (aka "awesome bar") as urlbar only (i.e. to enter URLs of pages I wish to see), nothing else. If it breaks "extra functionality" (e.g. the integrated search), I don't care as I don't use that anyway (Googlebar for "normal searches", and the search bar/multi-engine for "special searches" like Wikipedia, dictionaries, etc.) But if I weren't able to call up a web page by entering its URL, well, that would definitely be a show breaker :)

Comment: @Izzy You don't use the urlbar to access your bookmarks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33080/discussion-between-izzy-and-rockpaperlizard).

Comment: Just in case (because many don’t seem to know this), if a GUI (showing the icons) and drag-&-drop is not crucial, Firefox offers the most efficient way to search (well, at least in my opinion) by default: [using the address bar with user-defined keywords](http://superuser.com/a/488050/151741) -- nice thing is that this works for every input field, and sites don’t need to support OpenSearch.

Comment: @unor That is a very useful and underused technique.  Thanks.  Note that keywords are currently a bit buggy ( see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1179076 ), but still usable as long as you don't make many keyword changes.  If you like keywords, you may want to upvote that bug on bugzilla.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard there was an update to SecondSearch fixing issues with FF, so you might wish to re-check. With the latest changes Mozilla applied to the search engine, things got a bit strange: I finally got it working on the Windows machine at work – but at home on Linux, the cursor-key-driven popup is gone for good. I wasn't able to get that working again since switching to FF43 there :(

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  I'll take a second look at it.  :)  I also found that Drag & DropZones has received some good updates.  It is available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/drag-dropzones/

Comment: I'm not so much a "mouse guy" – I rather prefer the keyboard stuff of *Second Search* getting to work again on my Linux machine :(